# Get the nth last line from file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, files, tail

I have a file with quite many lines, and I would need the nth last line (specifically the 95th from bottom). How could I go on about doing this? One way would be to use tail but then it prints everything from last to 95th last, when I would only need the 95th.

Comment: Here is another easy way to do this using  `tac file | awk 'NR==95'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noted, you can use `tail` to get the last 95 lines from a file. You just want the first of these, for which there is a utility called `head`. So

```
tail -95 file | head -1
```

Using `tail` is probably the best you can do.

Another approach would be to read the lines into an array of lines, and just print out the n-95 line when you get to the end of the file. You don't actually need to store all the lines so you can have a circular buffer with 95 elements to store the last 95 lines you have read.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have worked in this case! :)

Answer (score 4):

[The answer of @icarus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/678701/4869) does the trick, but just to add another option:

```
tac file | sed -n 95p
```

`tac` will print the file in reverse, and `sed -n 95p` will print the 95th line. Since the file is printed in reverse, it will show the 95th line from the bottom.

##### Update

As @icarus mentioned in the comments:

> A downside is that the whole file is passed through the pipe, rather
> than just 95 lines. Telling sed to explicitly quit after printing the
> 95th line would remove this disadvantage.

So here's an updated command that quits after it prints the 95th line:

```
tac file | sed -n '95{p; q}'
```

Comment: This is indeed another way to do it. It has the advantage that if the file is shorter than 95 lines it will output nothing, rather than the first line. A downside is that the whole file is passed through the pipe, rather than just 95 kines. Telling sed to explicitly quit after printing the 95th line would remove this disadvantage.